# 406 Not Acceptable error for downloading table as xls

Tags: php, sql, excel

I have successfully run this php code using my laptop, but it failed when I tried it on a server.

The purpose of this file is to download table (SQL) into .xls format.

```
<?php
    session_start();

// Set name of excel doc

    if(isset($_POST['t'])){
        $setExcelName = $_POST['t'];
    }else{
        $setExcelName = 'Semua permohonan';
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['demo']) AND $_SESSION['demo'] = 'yes'){
        $demo = ' (DEMO)';
    }else{
        $demo = '';
    }


    include'connect.php';


// Define header / field name

    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM senaraipermohonan";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $setMainHeader = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowname = '';
        $rowname = '"'.$row['Field'].'"';
        $setMainHeader .= $rowname . "\t";
    }



// Set record in table

    if(isset($_POST['q'])){
        $sql = $_POST['q'];
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM senaraipermohonan";
    }
    $record = $conn->query($sql);

    if($record->num_rows >0){
        $setData = '';
        while ($row = $record->fetch_row()) {
            $rowData = '';
            foreach ($row as $value) {  
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
                $rowData .= $value;
            }

            $setData .= $rowData . "\n";
        }
    }else{
        $setData = "Tiada data";
    }

//This Header is used to make data download instead of display the data
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Permohonan SMAN2017 - " . $setExcelName . $demo . ".xls");

    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

//It will print all the Table row as Excel file row with selected column name as header.
    echo ucwords($setMainHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";


?>
```

It returns this:

```
 Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /download_as_excel.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What are the possible reaasons for this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error occures on handling an error.

So you have two things to do:

- find the error in handling the error document.
- find the original error

For the second I would look for the database credentials (username, password and so on) I would expect the error there. I think the username, password and db name is not the same on your laptop and on a server.